# Common format for time zone in Java/J2me

Tags: java, java-me, timezone, synchronization, dst

We are developing a j2me app for syncing contacts to/from a server. we are storing the update and create time (long mill sec) with each contact for conflict resolution/sync calculations.

Now as the client and server app can be in different time zones , how one can store time with time zone in a standard format (to take care diff time zones and daylight savings) for calculations at client and server side.

Comment: so on client and server if we store the time using System.currentTimeMillis() UTC , we don have to take care of time zones and daylight savings in our calculation for eg.

long time1 ;
long time2 ;

if(time1-time2 >0) time1 occurred after time2 ???

Answer (score 4):

If you use System.currentTimeMillis() you don't have to worry about time zones, because it is in universal time. From [System.currentTimeMillis() Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()):

public static long currentTimeMillis()

[...]

Returns:
    the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.

The time zone UTC is [Coordinated Universal Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), which is mostly GMT .

Comment: so on client and server if we store the time using System.currentTimeMillis() UTC , 

we don have to take care of time zones and daylight savings in our calculation for eg. 
long time1 ; 
long time2 ; 
if(time1-time2 >0) time1 occurred after time2 ???

Comment: Yes, time zones (including daylight savings time) are only taken into account for presenting dates to the user.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you store all times in GMT+0 and convert the time only when you display it.